# What is bit (or binary digit)?

Tags: c

So, if I were to represent 23 in binary, what are bits here? Are 0 and 1 called bits? What they mean when they say I have five bits of information?

Comment: The usual decimal number system uses *digits* between 1-9. The difference is that binary number system uses only two *digits*, 0 and 1. So a binary number may look like this: 1011101. In this example, the jumber is represented by $7$ binary digits, so hence we can "say" it contains $7$ bits of information. There are plenty of explanations online on how to convert decimal to binary or the other way around, you may be interested in searching for them.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number